# Understanding vector::assign example on cplusplus

Tags: c++, vector, assign

I am confused about the [following code](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/) and what it does:

```
first.assign (7,100);             // 7 ints with a value of 100

std::vector<int>::iterator it;
it=first.begin()+1;

second.assign (it,first.end()-1); // the 5 central values of first
```

I don't understand the `second.assign` statement. I would assume it assigns 100 elements in `second` with a value of 100. Why is the size of `second` 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example code

`it = vec.begin()+1` meaning 2nd element

And

```
second.assign (it,first.end()-1);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

One past the last element.
it has skipped the first and last elements and hence you have 7-2=5 elements in the last assignment.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 overloads of `assign` (3 in C++11).

- First assign uses `the new contents are n elements, each initialized to a copy of val.`
- 2nd assign uses `the new contents are elements constructed from each of the elements in the range between first and last, in the same order.`

Therefore the 2nd assign copies `first` from the 2nd element to the penultimate element.

Comment: ahh got it thank u!